# Strange behavior with taskScheduler pool

Tags: java, spring

I have two spring boot app (1.4.3.RELEASE) which are on the same server. The app A is a monolithic app which contains a part of code used to process alerts and the app B is a new dedicated app which only process alerts. The goal here is to break the monolotic app in small apps. For now, the two codes run together because I have old systems which always call the app A.

The two app have a taskScheduler configured based on a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.

```
@Configuration
public class TaskSchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(100);

        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }
}
```

Yesterday, I have experienced a strange behavior :

1. An alert has been detected and sent to the new app B -> OK
2. The app B received the alert and start to process it based on the taskScheduler -> OK
3. The first step has been processed by the app B -> OK
4. The second step has been processed by the app A -> NOK, strange behavior
5. The third step has been processed by the app B as expected -> OK

How can this be possible? For me, each taskScheduler is attached to the app which created it. Where am I wrong?

UPDATE

I have a real box which emit alerts. Those alerts must be processed by a new application. But I have also old box which have not migrate to the new system. So I have the processing code in two different projects.

I have a new box with the new code which have created an alert on the new system. This alert generate a state machine which is processed in async with a task scheduler. After alert creation, the new app starts to process the state machine and at the middle of the processing the old application wake up and process a step of the alert. After that, the new application wake up again and normally close the alert.

The problem is : why the old application wake up to process an alert? Is there a known issue with a threadPoolTaskScheduler?

Comment: Define same server... As in deployed to the same tomcat instance, or running on the physical machine as 2 separate instances.

Comment: Same physical machine but two tomcat different instance. It's a spring boot based applications so each one has a tomcat embedded instance.

Comment: There must be something that is shared between them (writing things out to a file system, db etc).

Comment: They share the same database but I don't see why there is an impact on an async processing method.

Comment: If they share the same database they do read that data (else the second one wouldn't be processed by the other application). Also are you really sure that it was processed by the second application and that it wasn't a glitch in your logging? Or how have you determined this?

Comment: What is that strange behavior?

Comment: @M.Deinum Yep I'm sure that it has been processed on step 3 by application B and then processing is back on application A on step 4.

Comment: Then both must read the same stuff and process the same stuff but that isn't clear from your question... Too little information.

Comment: So I will try to explain.

Comment: are you deploying both apps to the same managed environment (same Tomcat) which would make them share the class loader or do they run in separate JVMs?

Comment: @diginoise The two applications are two Spring Boot based applications with two seperate embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Cool, what about their classpaths? Do they share the classpaths, or is each app built into a self contained fat JAR file and can run without any external dependencies?

Comment: @diginoise It's two fat JAR file which are launched separately.

Comment: nice one! does the double invocation (AppA triggered) happens every time AppB receives the alert? What are these alerts? Could both apps simply be reacting to the same signal?

Comment: @diginoise It only happens once. The box calls a REST endpoint to register the alert on AppA. After that, I used a threadPoolTaskScheduler to manage the state machine. There is apparently no reason for AppB to manage just 1 step of the state machine.

Comment: @FranckYapadesouciAnso have you finally figure it out?

Comment: @fornarat No, not for the moment. I always investigate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that two different applications have this behavior since they are running in isolated processes. Threads (of the same process) run in a shared memory space, while processes run in separate memory spaces, so there is no 'bridge' between them.

If they share the same database, they might be listening to the same events, but only if you have that logic implemented by you.

If I had to guess, given that both are webapps I'd say that there might be some HTTP call somewhere in the code, still aiming to an old endpoint, or some other trigger (crons?) inside the server that is kickstarting the old app.